# $.getJSON - display individual headers

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm new to JQuery and JSON.

I am trying to retrieve JSON from my server, and display each section in a different headers of a HTML file. I'm not entirely sure how to do that, tried a lot of things, I've managed to get it so the JSON is displayed in Chrome's console log.

Now I don't really understand how I can grab each individual section of JSON to display in a different div. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://10.240.211.221:5000/questions/1", function(result){
            console.log(result);
            });
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<h1 id="question">Question will go here</h1>

<div id="optionA">
option A will go here
</div>

<div id="optionB">
option B will go here
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "question": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "a": "Yes",
      "aResult": 0,
      "b": "No",
      "bResult": 0,
      "question": "Are Jaffa Cakes biscuits?"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery you can use the `.text()` (http://api.jquery.com/text/) method. I wrote up an example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://10.240.211.221:5000/questions/1", function(result){
          var question = result.questions[0];
          $(".question").text(question.question);
          $(".optionA").text(question.a);
          $(".optionB").text(question.b);
        });
      });
    });


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button>Get JSON data</button>

    <h1 class="question"></h1>

    <div class="optionA"></div>

    <div class="optionB"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This will only display 1 question from an array so if you are returning multiple messages and want to map over them you can use something like this.

```
  $.getJSON("http://10.240.211.221:5000/questions", function(result){
    var questions = result.questions;
    questions.map(function(question) {
      $('<div/>', {
        html: $('<h1/>', {
          html: question.question
        })
        .after(
          $('<div/>', {
            'text': question.a,
            'class': 'optionA'
          })
        )
        .after(
          $('<div/>', {
            'text': question.b,
            'class': 'optionB'
          })
        )
      }).appendTo('body');
    });
  });
```

Comment: When clicking the button, I receive 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'.

What could cause that?

Comment: I wrote the example based on your initial question. You have to check what your response `result` is. I defined `question` as `var question = result.questions[0];` so i am assuming there is no questions array on the result.

Comment: I should've specified that result returns the JSON in my original question. It does return something.

Comment: Yes I know it returns JSON but you need to look at the response because as I mentioned my example is assuming the response looks like the JSON in your question.

Comment: I got it working, it was question[0] rather than questions[0].
I guess I just needed a think about it before I went for it.

Answer (score 0):

you arent too far off!

for example:

```
var foo = {
  "question": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "a": "Yes",
      "aResult": 0,
      "b": "No",
      "bResult": 0,
      "question": "Are Jaffa Cakes biscuits?"
    }
  ]
};
```

`console.log(foo.question.id)` will return `1`
`console.log(foo.question.question)` will return `Are Jaffa Cakes Biscuits?`

then you can just push them into the divs as needed with jquery:

```
$('#div-a').text(foo.question.question);
```

or you can add a new div to #div-a:

```
$('#div-a').append($('<div>'>).text(foo.question.question)
```